# How can I use filter option in django rest framework using function based view

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

Here is my model:

```
  class Customer(models.Model):
       name   = models.CharField(max_length=250) 
       age    = models.IntegerField()
       status = models.IntegerField()
```

And the serializer is :

```
 class CustomerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

       class Meta:
            model  = Customer
            fields = '__all__'
```

I want to use filter option for the Customer model with their age and status, which will pass by json format (not in the urls) using POST method. How can I implement the filter option? I am using function based view here.

```
 {
      "age": 20,
      "status": 2
 }
```

If I sent this json then it will filter out the Customer model.

Comment: Please, can you show the serializer and viewset?

Comment: Come on, please write your serializer and view classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplejson to deserialize the data,since it looks like a simple json.

`from django.utils import simplejson
data = simplejson.loads(request.POST['data'])`

Then you can access the values of data dictionery by `data.key`.

You can now use chained filter to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
If your post josn from body form data.

```
from django.db.models import Q
        age = self.request.POST.get('age')
        status = self.request.POST.get("status")
        q_objects = Q()
        if age:
            q_objects.add(Q(age=age), Q.AND)
        if status:
            q_objects.add(Q(status=status), Q.AND)
        if q_objects:
            queryset = Customer.objects.filter(q_objects)
        else:
            queryset = Customer.objects.all()
```